# Setting the minimum password length in Group Policy

Tags: c++, winapi, policy

I wrote a code using the windows API [NetUserModalsSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusermodalsset) function to set the minimum password length. 
Now, this has different levels(structures) to set what we want

[USER_MODALS_INFO_0](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_modals_info_0)  this structure allows us to give a maimum value for the password length as LM20_PWLEN(14). If any value greater than this is given, it returns Invalid parameters error. But since i want to set it to more than that, i used [USER_MODALS_INFO_1001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_modals_info_1001) as it allows PWLEN(256).

When i use the USER_MODALS_INFO_1001 structure with a password length > 14, it returns invalid parameter error. But if i define it as 14, it is working properly. Now this should have worked with any password length <= 256 but didn't.

Is there a reason why this is exhibiting this behavior? I have attached a snippet of my code

```
    USER_MODALS_INFO_1001 pBufPass;
    DWORD mode = 1001, value = 17,parm_err;
    printf("The minimum password length is going to be set as %lu\n",value);
    pBufPass.usrmod1001_min_passwd_len = value;
    printf("Value that is going to be set is : %lu\n",pBufPass.usrmod1001_min_passwd_len);
    NET_API_STATUS nStatus = NetUserModalsSet(NULL, mode, (LPBYTE)&pBufPass, &parm_err);
    if (nStatus != NERR_Success)
    {
        printf("Error while using NetUserModalsSet. Error code : %lu and parm_err : %lu\n", nStatus, parm_err);
        ret = false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the output when it fails?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker Error while using NetUserModalsSet. Error code : 87 and parm_err : 1

Comment: @BharathSuresh Your code works for me. Can you have a double check if this is a reproducible sample? What's your Windows version?

Comment: Here are a couple of references to check out: [Minimum password length (Windows 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/minimum-password-length) and [What is the maximum length of password in Windows 10?](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/maximum-length-of-password-windows-10).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT
I tested it in a windows 7 64 bit system

Comment: @BharathSuresh Yes, I can reproduce this issue on Windows 7. It seems the document needs some update. I'll submit an document issue internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parameter `usrmod1001_min_passwd_len` of [`USER_MODALS_INFO_1001`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_modals_info_1001#requirements) structure:

- **Windows 7** support value **0 and 14**.
- **Windows 10** (test version 1903) support value between **0 and 256** (`PWLEN`).